# Flutter How to make it vibrate on the last count?

Tags: flutter, logic, vibration

I made a counter application, the user can determine the number of their own count. if the count reaches the count limit, I want it vibrate at the last count. For example, if I specify the number 5, the smartphone will vibrate on the 5th tap. However, I have a problem, because the vibration appears on the 6th tap.

How to make it vibrate on the 5th beat?

**here is my code:**

```
int _counter = 0;
int _five = 5;


onTap: () async {
  setState(() {
    if (_counter != _five) {
      _counter++;
    } else if (_counter == _five) {
      Vibration.vibrate(duration: 500);
      _counter = _counter + 0;
    } else {}
      });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code need a little change like:

```
  onTap: () async {
    setState(() {
      if (_counter < _five) {
        _counter++;
      }
      if (_counter == _five) {
        Vibration.vibrate(duration: 500);
      } else {}
    });
  }
```

Comment: Wooow... thank you so much Sir... :), it's works!

Comment: @AryAnzh The reason is that when the 5th time hit button, the UI will display 5 (since it fire the first condition not the second one), then hit button again, it fire the second one. That is why it always vibrate in 6th time.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge, sir, I'm starting to understand flutter from this web

Comment: @AryAnzh I think you may need [Dart](https://dart.dev/codelabs) and [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/codelabs) Code Lab